# How do I fix socketio spamming polling when I start my web app? [javascript, expressjs, socketio]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, polling

[Here is the problem. When I load the page in the browser and check to see if my "test" was emitted, I run into this wall of spamming polling.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obJ4w.png)

The code I use is exactly the same as in other projects I have done, so it makes no sense to me that this doesn't work now. -_-

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server ready - listening on *:8000');
});

app.get( '/*' , function( req, res, next ) {
    //This is the current file they have requested
    var file = req.params[0];
    //Send the requesting client the file.
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/' + file );
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('test', function(){
        console.log("test worked");
    });
});
```

client.js

```
var socket = io();
socket.emit("test");
```

I broke the code down to what you see above. There's nothing else. And it doesn't work. *internal screaming*

Comment: What browser are you running this in?  And, are you 100% sure you have the same version of socket.io running in both client and server?  If you use `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` in the client, then it will always load the client directly from the server, guaranteeing they are the same version.  It seems like your client code thinks it never successfully connects.

Comment: Omg that was it, I think. I used *both* that script link and <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script> for a while now without a hitch. Now that I "commented" the cdn.socket script (removed basically), it just worked! Yessss thank you for your beautiful eyes looking where i could not. <3

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my comment as an answer so you can wrap up this question.  One common reason that socket.io will loop with http requests and never successfully connect is if you are running mismatched version on the client and server.  This seems to have happened recently with socket.io upon a recent version change so they must have made some change in how the connection logic works that makes it fail to connect if versions are mismatched.

If you load your client via this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Then, the client will always match the server version as long as you don't have any other `<script>` tags that are loading some other version of socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution which worked for me ( Socket.IO 2.3.0 and Socket.IO Client 2.3.0 ) is to set the `transports` field when you create the instance of `io` on back-end and `socket` on front-end , like this :

On back-end :

```
    io = require('socket.io')(http,{ 
            log: false,
            agent: false,
            origins : '*:*' , // this is for the CORS browser error , I also use the cors npm module here
            transports : [ 'websocket' ]
    });
```

And on front-end :

```
const socket = socketIOClient(url,{ 
        forceNew : false , 
        secure : true ,
        transports: [ 'websocket' ] 
});
```

Hope it helps , if not the question owner , then maybe the others :)